# Will Bash on Ubuntu on Windows be available for 32-bit Operating Systems?

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, 32-bit

Windows announced that the [Anniversary Update](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/06/29/windows-10-anniversary-update-available-august-2/) of Windows 10 on August 2nd 2016 will include a feature called ["Bash on Ubuntu on Windows"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about).

Users who receive insider builds have already had a chance to install this feature, but it looks like (so far) it has only been released for 64-bit versions of the Windows 10 OS.

Have Microsoft made any announcement regarding whether Bash will be available for 32-bit versions of Windows 10? If so, will the 32-bit release be available at the same time?

Comment: after reading the super-user tour and FAQ, i'm still not 100% sure whether this type of question is on-topic or not. i'm happy to edit or move my question as appropriate if i get feedback.

Comment: This feature will be aviable for all versions of Windows 10 once Version 1608 (aka the Anniversary Update) is released.  I won't be submitting an answer since, the Anniversary Update has not been released, and I can't actually prove that this is the case outside of the fact my 32-bit installations of Windows 10 with the current Anniversary Update Insider Preview build the Ubuntu on Windows feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Most (if not all) Intel and AMD CPUs in the last decade support the x86-64 instruction set and there's no reason for Microsoft to spend time and money into supporting a 32-bit version of Linux. Most developers and Ubuntu users are running the 64-bit version anyway

> ## Prerequisites
>
> Your PC must be running (at a minimum) a 64-bit version of Windows 10 Anniversary Update. Creators Update is recommended.

https://web.archive.org/web/20170628194954/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide

> Important: **To run Bash/WSL, you must be running a 64-bit version of Windows 10 on a 64-bit PC**. If you do NOT see “Windows Subsystem for Linux” listed in the optional features, you are likely not running a 64-bit version of Windows 10, or are running a build of Windows 10 prior to #14316.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/04/06/bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-download-now-3/